# Flyback diode rating questions

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, flyback

I'm currently working on a magnetic levitation project which revolves around levitating an object below an electromagnet. This was inspired by a [magnetic levitation project](https://www.hackster.io/jsirgado/magnet-levitation-with-arduino-eeeee4) that I found online.

The thing is, however, that I tried this with some steel balls weighing 3.4 grams from [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00HPX4CF4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and when actually testing the system, the steel ball would not detect the electromagnet's field unless it was 0.5 mm away from it. Strangely enough, the coil (of 644 turns) has an iron core inside it.

Due to this, I was considering increasing the current beyond 1 A just to increase the strength, but was worried if I had to get a higher rating flyback diode due to the flyback EMF from the coil potentially increasing. Therefore, am I supposed to get a higher rating diode? Or do something else?

Comment: _”the steel ball would not detect the electromagnet's field unless it was 0.5 mm away from it”_ Technically, it did along with every other magnetic field in the universe but either you (if you were holding it) or your test setup didn’t.

Answer (score 3):

Maximum current in the flyback diode will be the same as the maximum current that you drive the coil with.

So, if you drive the coil with 1 A, you need a 1 A (with some margin of course) rated flyback diode.

Comment: Ah alright, got it thank you very much!